# send generated pdf (with dompdf) to email without saving on server and without pear class

Tags: html, css, dompdf

Is it possible to send dompdf generated PDF to email, without saving PDF on server and without using pear classes?

I have found sollutions only for:
1) saving pdf on server and then adding it as attachement or
2) Using some pear class

Both of those doesn't fit me. I am having pdf in variable:

```
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a PEAR class? What about a non-PEAR class? Basically all you need is to be able to write the email content on-the-fly. It's possible to write your own email-generating script (a la @mti2935's answer), but I would use an existing class unless you're willing to learn the details of email formats.

Answer (score 5):

I think you ought to be able to base64-encode the PDF information which you've stored as a string in $pdf, insert directly into a multipart mime email, and send it using PHP's mail() function, like below:

```
    // to, from, subject, message body, attachment filename, etc.
    $to = "to@to.com";
    $from = "from@from.com";
    $subject = "subject";
    $message = "this is the message body";        
    $fname="nameofpdfdocument.pdf";

    $headers = "From: $from"; 
    // boundary 
    $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

    // headers for attachment 
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

    // multipart boundary 
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

    // preparing attachment            
        $data=$pdf;
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
        $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/pdf\"};\n" . " name=\"$fname\"\n" . 
        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$fname\"\n" . 
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";


    // send
    //print $message;

    $ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f " . $from);
```

Comment: Would it appear as attachement?

Comment: It is not working. Actually I do not know how to test it and understand why it is not working. It is sending email, but without any  pdf.

Comment: Interesting.  I tested this just now on a LAMP server, and it worked - I received an email with the PDF document attached.  In your test, are you sure $pdf contains PDF data?  If so, I would be curious to see what the full source of the email that you received looks like.  Is there anything in the MIME section where the PDF should be?

Comment: Thanks Dear for this solution. :)